# How to get my git-integrated Kaleidoscope to display all files that are about to be committed?

Tags: git, diff

I'm using command-line git and [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/) to perform my code reviews. When I merge a branch into another and type

```
git difftool
```

Kaleidoscope only displays changes that are 'not staged for commit' and don't display 'unmerged paths' or 'changed to be committed'.

The command-line displays the rest of the stuff.

Any idea why?

This is the relevant content of my `.gitconfig`

```
[difftool "Kaleidoscope"]
        cmd = ksdiff-wrapper git \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[diff]
        tool = Kaleidoscope
[difftool]
        prompt = false
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Short answer: what you want to be typing on the command line is `git difftool HEAD`, not `git difftool`.

Long answer: This is normal git behavior, and it's kind of frustrating if you don't realize what's happening.  I'm not sure why the command-line diff is working as you expect, but both `git diff` and `git difftool` should be performing similarly as per the git man page:

> git diff [--options] [--] [<path>...]
>              This form is to view the changes you made relative to the index (staging area for the next commit). In other words,
>              the differences are what you could tell git to further add to the index but you still haven't. You can stage these
>              changes by using git-add(1).

So `git diff` and `git difftool` should show you only **unstaged** changes.

If you want to see **staged** changes, you should use `git diff --cached` and `git difftool --cached` instead:

> git diff [--options] --cached [<commit>] [--] [<path>...]
>              This form is to view the changes you staged for the next commit relative to the named <commit>. Typically you would
>              want comparison with the latest commit, so if you do not give <commit>, it defaults to HEAD. If HEAD does not exist
>              (e.g. unborned branches) and <commit> is not given, it shows all staged changes. --staged is a synonym of --cached.

Finally, if you want to see **both staged and unstaged** changes, you use the third form, `git diff HEAD` or `git difftool HEAD`:

> git diff [--options] <commit> [--] [<path>...] This form is to view
>   the changes you have in your working tree relative to the named
>   <commit>. You can use HEAD to compare it with the latest commit, or a
>   branch name to compare with the tip of a different branch.

Answer (score 1):

```
git difftool --staged
```

Will give you exactly that.

`staged` in this case is a synonym for `cached`, though I find `staged` easier to remember.